# How to run python on multiple folder to create pdf?

Tags: python, loops, pdf, pdf-generation, fpdf

The following code is to combine multiple images into one pdf. I am trying to run this code on multiple folder where each folder has several images as result, each folder will has one pdf.

```
import os
from PIL import Image
from fpdf import FPDF


pdf = FPDF()
sdir = "imageFolder/"
w,h = 0,0

for i in range(1, 100):
    fname = sdir + "IMG%.3d.png" % i
    if os.path.exists(fname):
        if i == 1:
            cover = Image.open(fname)
            w,h = cover.size
            pdf = FPDF(unit = "pt", format = [w,h])
        image = fname
        pdf.add_page()
        pdf.image(image,0,0,w,h)
    else:
        print("File not found:", fname)
    print("processed %d" % i)
pdf.output("output.pdf", "F")
print("done")
```

I was thinking to create another loop to bring the folder path which will come before the first loop:

```
   For j in range(1 to 70):
folderP=sdir+folder%1
```

And loop in each folder

Sorry I am still learning python. Any suggestion would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `glob` to get the paths of all pdfs and add them to a list, then you just iterate through the list and you wouldn't even need to check if they exist:

```
from glob import glob

sDir = 'imageFolder/'
pdfPaths = []

pdfPaths.extend(glob(f'{sDir}**/*.pdf', recursive=True))

for pdf in pdfPaths:
    # do stuff
```

Comment: Could you have a look on the updated code, do you think, it should be in this way?

Comment: ? You literally copy pasted what I've written without integrating it in your code. Furthermore, you shouldn't edit the question with the solution, that's not how this site works. What I've given you creates a list with the paths of all the pdfs it finds (replace `*.pdf` with the extension you want). You should then do your operations over those files as you wish where `# do stuff` is.

Comment: I assume you know the code will be massy if copy and paste it in the comment, this is why I update the code. Definitely your answer was helpful. I am just trying to put all part of code together. Literally, this is my first time work on python and I am seeking for help! Thanks